# How to display this different in Excel?

Tags: r, excel

I did some calculations in R and I want to produce it into excel like this

```
DATA1          DATA2

54.364         2.05

56.532

54.21

41.485

65.8745

54.0546

75.156
```

but instead is coming like this

```
DATA1          DATA2

54.364         2.05

56.532         2.05

54.21          2.05

41.485         2.05

65.8745        2.05

54.0546        2.05

75.156         2.05
```

My function to produce it in excel is

```
write.xlsx(c(data.frame(DATA1),data.frame(DATA2)))
```

Although `data1` has values of 54.364, 56.532, 54.21, 41.485, 65.8745, 54.0546, 75.156 and `data2` 2.05

Answer (score 3):

Excel has a rather bizarre "copy down" feature where it copies a function returning a scalar into every cell in the calling range. It appears that this is happening to you here.

One way to work round this is to use `Application.Caller` at the top of the function that's called directly. This returns a `Range` object denoting the calling range. You can then pad your function return values with `#N/A`. You do this by inserting `variant` types into your array set to `VT_ERROR` and the error vales set to `xlErrNa`. You can use `CVErr(xlErrNa)` to do that in one step. Padding with `#N/A` matches what Excel does with oversized calling ranges for functions returning arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Following code can also be used: 
(using @akrun's data in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547210/how-to-produce-this-order-in-r)

```
DATA1 <- c(54.364, 56.532, 54.21, 41.845, 65.8745, 54.0546, 75.156)
DATA2 <- 2.05
DATA3 <- c(2.2, 2.4, 2.32)

outdf = data.frame(data1=numeric(), data2=numeric(), data3=numeric())
for(i in 1:length(DATA1)) outdf[i,]=c(DATA1[i],0,0)
for(i in 1:length(DATA2)) outdf$data2[i]=DATA2[i]
for(i in 1:length(DATA3)) outdf$data3[i]=DATA3[i]
outdf
    data1 data2 data3
1 54.3640  2.05  2.20
2 56.5320  0.00  2.40
3 54.2100  0.00  2.32
4 41.8450  0.00  0.00
5 65.8745  0.00  0.00
6 54.0546  0.00  0.00
7 75.1560  0.00  0.00
```

Then you can use outdf with write.xlsx .